# How can I build a custom .xctoolchain from custom LLVM source?

Tags: xcode, toolchain

1. I just copied the default toolchain to ~/Library/Developer/Toolchains/ but Xcode shows "The toolchain is not compatible with this version of Xcode."
2. I just simply replaced the compiler in it with llvm 5.0, but Xcode shows the same problem.
3. I just simply changed the identifier at the .plist file, same problem...

How can I build a custome .xctoolchain file?

Comment: did you ever figure this out?